# Rest api authentication in javascript

Tags: javascript, perl, rest

I am trying to use a REST api with JavaScript and can't seem to get it to work. I have a Perl equivalent which is as follows:

```
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => 'https://someurl');
$req->content_type('application/xml');
$req->headers(Accept => 'application/xml; charset=utf-8');
$req->authorization_basic('username','password');
$req->content($body);
```

This is the request. How do I do this in JavaScript, I looked online and couldn't find anything obvious for syntax.

Comment: I would like to see a straight javascript solution just out of curiosity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will useful to user jquery framework and  make ajax call like

```
    $.ajax({
'url': '/someurl',
async:false,
'beforeSend': function(xhr) {
     xhr.setRequestHeader("Authentication", "Basic " + encodeBase64(username + ":" + password) 
}});
```

Comment: Anyone can now view and use your username and password.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the `.ajax`method. See http://dothow.blogspot.com/2009/05/http-basic-authentication-with-jquery.html for an example of basic authorization from jquery.